# Python tuple duplication with *

Tags: python, tuples

This works just fine and straight-forward:

```
>>> ('a',) * 3
    ('a', 'a', 'a')
```

But I was experimenting with tuple a little and came across this:

```
>>> 'a', * ('b', 'c')
    ('a', 'b', 'c')

>>> ('a',) * ('b', 'c')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        ('a',) * ('b', 'c')
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

Can anybody explain how did the `*` make the tuple concatenate in the line `'a', * ('b', 'c')`?

Comment: that's not concatenation that's unpacking of `('b','c')

Comment: If you expected that to give you the Cartesian product of those items, see [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: `'a', * ('b', 'c')` is not using the multiplication operator as `__mul__`, it is used for *unpacking*

Answer (score 4):

In this expression

```
'a', * ('b', 'c')
```

You have two primary things going on

1. `'a',` creates a tuple with a single element `'a'`
2. `* ('b', 'c')` uses extended iterable unpacking ([PEP 3132](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/))

So the result of #2 is used to continue the tuple definition from #1. To show a more intuitive example this is the same idea

```
>>> 'a', *range(5)
('a', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: I would rephrase, `'a', * ('b', 'c')` does not create a tuple with a single element, it is a tuple literal with a single explicit element and an unpacking expression (which involves another tuple literal)

Comment: Extended iterable unpacking applies to assignment. This is an "additional unpacking generalization" from [PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/), if I'm not mistaken.